# Passing newMangagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to pass the newManagedObject to another viewcontroller, so i can make a relationship between my Song and Playlist entity.

Here i'm saving my object:

```
-(void)saveTap:(id)sender{
    newManagedObject = (Playlists*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Playlists" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [newManagedObject setValue:self.textfield.text forKey:@"playlistName"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self fetchDevices];
}
```

fetchDevices method:

```
- (void)fetchDevices {
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Playlists"];
    devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableViewData reloadData];
}
```

On select i pass the newManagedObject to my Singleton [rowNumber singleObj]
The problem is that it returns nil instead of the playlistName. How can implement indexpath.row, so it will return the selectedRow playlistName.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    newManagedObject = (Playlists*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Playlists" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

    optionsSingle = [rowNumber singleObj];

    optionsSingle.selectedRowNow = newManagedObject;
    NSLog(@"%@", optionsSingle.selectedRowNow);


    SongsViewController *songsViewController = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SongsViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:songsViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: What is other part of code... and this is not clear by this snipet... may be it is due to scope or you accessing before creating object... please add some meaningful code

Comment: I'm trying to pass managedObject to another ViewController, so i can create a core data relationship. Thats why i need to pass the newManagedObject.

Comment: It will better if you place some code... from where you passing and where you are accessing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  devices is your Fetched Results Controller then you should be able to get the record that corresponds to the row that was clicked using:

```
[devices objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This seem to work. playlistName = newPlaylist;
    songs = "<relationship fault: 0xbe7d850 'songs'>";

does relationship fault, means there is an error or just because there is no Songs associated with it?

Comment: I believe the relationship fault means that is has not been loaded yet, but would be when needed. Faults are nothing to fear in this case :)